# Add PhoneGap to existing native app

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have an existing objectiveC native app for iPhone. Can i add a button in native app so that clicking on to that will bring up phonegap UI (ie, which use phonegap framework). Is there any way to acheive this.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I know/explored -

On click of a button you can open up an HTML page in your web view(as we do it while building a PhoneGap app.). 
But if you want to open the same Native App to get converted in PhoneGap app that's not going to work for sure.

Hope it helps. :)